# Where to perform final processing before application closes?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

I have been trying to write out data to storage when the form closes or the application terminates and have NOT been successful.

I first tried from the Form unit

```
procedure TForm1.FinalizeObject;
begin
inherited;
SaveData;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TForm1.FinalizeObject;
begin 
 SaveData;  
 inherited;
end;
```

neither of these attempts worked, therefore I rrearranged my code and tried it from the project’s unit

```
procedure TApplication.ApplicationClosing;
begin 
 SaveData; 
 inherited;
end;
```

and

```
procedure TApplication.ApplicationClosing;
begin 
 inherited; 
 SaveData;
end;
```

I have a w3_showmessage as the first line of SaveData, and it never gets called ever....so, if i can verify that one of these 4 methods is triggered, i could use one of them

What am i doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I believe neither FinalizeObject nor ApplicationClosing are called when the browser window is closed. Don't know about on-device applications, though (but would suspect the same).

Comment: As I stated, neither of these are called when i close my app down

Comment: Well, I was just confirming this :) I sent your question to the author of Smart Mobile Studio but he's on vacation until next week ...

Comment: Hi gabr, i got an answer back from them. Because my SaveData line has a w3_showmessage as the first line, then the rest of the routine isn't called. You can't use a w3_showmessage in the finalizeObject or ApplicationClosing  methods.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I think you should write an answer to your own question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of writing, Smart exposes two new events in the application object:

- OnUnload
- OnBeforeUnload

These will make it easier to handle shutdown sequences. The smart javascript bootstrap also calls application.terminate() automatically now, so your code should work fine.